# Interesting special functions identity involving the inner product of real spherical harmonics with a cosecant weight function

Tags: special-functions, inner-products, spherical-harmonics

In spherical coordinates $\Omega=(\theta,\phi)\in[0,\pi]\otimes[0,2\pi]$, define the inner product
$$C_{L_1m_1}^{L_2m_2}:=\left\langle Y_{L_1m_1},\rho,Y_{L_2m_2}\right\rangle=\int Y_{L_1m_1}(\Omega)\rho(\Omega)Y_{L_2m_2}(\Omega)\,d\Omega$$
where $Y_{Lm}(\Omega)$ is the real spherical harmonic
$$Y_{Lm}(\theta,\phi)=(-1)^m\sqrt{\frac{(2L+1)}{2\pi}\frac{(L-|m|)!}{(L+|m|)!}}P_L^{|m|}(\cos(\theta))\times\begin{cases}
\sin(|m|\phi)&m<0\\
\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}&m=0\\
\cos(|m|\phi)&m>0
\end{cases}$$
and $\rho(\theta,\phi)=\csc^2(\theta)$.

Testing in Mathematica has led me to conjecture that
$$C_{L_1m_1}^{L_2m_2}=\frac{L_1+1/2}{|m_1|}\delta_{L_1L_2}\delta_{m_1m_2}$$
except when $m_1=m_2=0$, in which case the integral does not converge. So far, this appears to be valid for all integers up to $0\leq L_1,L_2\leq5$ and $0\leq |m_1|\leq L_1,0\leq |m_2|\leq L_2$ (ie, Mathematica was able to symbolically verify it for the first 1296 cases).

Assuming that this is true, **is there a systematic way to prove it**? I am vaguely aware of the usual identities involving the inner product of two real harmonics $\left\langle Y_{L_1m_1},Y_{L_2m_2}\right\rangle=\delta_{L_1,L_2}\delta_{m_1m_2}$ and the more complicated one involving the product of three (involving Clebsch-Gordan coefficients), but I don't see how they're directly applicable to the case where there's a $\frac{1}{\sin(\theta)^2}$ multiplying the two harmonics.

Also, is there a general formula where the weight function can be other trigonometric functions, such as $\rho(\theta,\phi)=\sin^{-1}(\theta),\cot(\theta)$, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This falls under Sturm-Liouville Theory of second order symmetric differential operator
$$
              LF=\frac{1}{w}\frac{d}{dx}\rho\frac{d}{dx}F,\;\;\; a < x < b,
$$
where $\rho$ and $w$ are positive on $(a,b)$. Such operators have a useful so-called adjoint equation
$$
                 (LF)G-F(LG) = \frac{1}{w}\frac{d}{dx}\{\rho(F'G-FG')\}.
$$
It's the adjoint equation that leads to orthogonality, provided conditions are carefully chosen at the endpoints. Specifically, suppose that $F$, $G$ are eigenfunctions of $L$ with eigenvalues $\lambda$, $\mu$, respectively; i.e., suppose $LF=\lambda F$ and $LG=\mu G$. Then
$$
             (\lambda-\mu)wFG = \frac{d}{dx}\{\rho(F'G-FG')\},
$$
which leads to
$$
           \left.(\lambda-\mu)\int_{a}^{b}wFG\,dx = \rho(F'G-FG')\right|_{a}^{b}
$$
If $F$ and $G$ are in $L^{2}_{w}(a,b)$, meaning that
$$
      \int_{a}^{b}w|F|^{2}\,dx < \infty,\;\;\; \int_{a}^{b}w|G|^{2}\,dx < \infty,
$$
then $(F,G)_{w}=\int_{a}^{b}wFG\,dx$ converges absolutely and, automatically, the evaluation terms must exist as $x$ approaches $a$ or $b$. By imposing conditions are the endpoints to make the evaluation terms vanish, you end up with $(\lambda -\mu)(F,G)=0$, which forces $(F,G)=0$ for eigenfunctions with different eigenvalues. In some cases you don't need conditions at the endpoints at all, which is your case. This can happen when $\rho$ vanishes at the endpoints of the interval (but it doesn't have to happen): you can see some reason how this might be related to the adjoint equation.

The equation you have for the the functions of $\theta$ is really unusual in that it may be viewed as an eigenfunction equation in *two* ways. That's how you end up with two sets of orthogonality conditions. You've just discovered the second orthogonality set of orthogonality conditions. Setting $x=\cos\theta$ transforms your equation to the form
$$
    \left[\frac{d}{dx}(1-x^{2})\frac{d}{dx}-\frac{m^{2}}{1-x^{2}}+n(n+1)\right]P_{n}^{m}(x)=0,
$$
For fixed $m$, you end up with weight $w=1$ and eigenvalues $n(n+1)$. For fixed $n$, you end up with weight $w=1/(1-x^{2})$ and eigenvalues $m^{2}$.

Except for the case where $m=0$, I know of no simple way to get the normalization constants. It's all a bit of tedious integration by parts applied to explicit forms of $P_{n}^{m}$ expressed using the Rodrigues formula.